# Suggestions for constructing ggplot2 useable dataset from list of matrices and vectors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape, reshape2

I wish to make ggplot2 graphics for functional data.  Often, functional data are stored as different matrices.  Thus, the goal is a swift reshaping of the data.  As an example, below is my rough-pass for taking the fda:::growth dataset in R, which is a list of three objects:  one matrix for boys ('hgtm'), one matrix for girls (hgtf), and a vector of the common ages they were measured.

Copied from the help manual for fda:

*growth: Berkeley Growth Study data*

Description

A list containing the heights of 39 boys and 54 girls from age 1 to 18 and the ages at which they were collected.

Format

This list "growth" contains the following components:

hgtm a 31 by 39 numeric matrix giving the heights in centimeters of 39 boys at 31 ages.

hgtf a 31 by 54 numeric matrix giving the heights in centimeters of 54 girls at 31 ages.

age a numeric vector of length 31 giving the ages at which the heights were measured.

Details

The ages are not equally spaced.

How can one more succinctly get through this reshaping so those in functional data analysis will be more likely to make plots using ggplot2?

```
## take the list 'growth' from fda package and make dataframe 'gg.growth'
require(fda); require(ggplot2)
gg.growth <- with(growth, data.frame(age=rep(age, ncol(hgtf)+ncol(hgtm)),
                                     hgt=c(hgtf,hgtm),
                                     sex=c(rep("female", length(age)*ncol(hgtf)),
                                           rep("male"  , length(age)*ncol(hgtm)))))

## add 'id' variable for subsetting
gg.growth$id <- with(growth,rep(1:(ncol(hgtf)+ncol(hgtm)), each=length(age)))

## make a ggplot
ggplot(subset(gg.growth, id %in% c(1,40,88,93 )), 
       aes(x=age, y=hgt, colour=sex, group=id), alpha=.5) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reshape2` is very powerful for this type of thing:

```
library(reshape2)
growth.mlt <- melt(growth[-3])  # don't need 3rd element since it is in rownames
```

That's it.  Now you can plot:

```
ggplot(growth.mlt, aes(x=Var1, y=value, group=Var2)) +
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ L1)
```

Here we plot height vs. age for males and females separately:

[image]

Clearly the plot will benefit from better labeling, but you get the idea.